# Multiple Google Cloud Functions : how to manage internal lib?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I've a project with multiple cloud functions using nodejs 10, some of them doing the same kind of stuff like querying Firestore/MySQL (so same initialisation code) or using the same block of code in the functions.

How can I put this code in a library that is used inside my project alone ?

The only thing I know would work, would be to make a public library and publish it on npmjs, which is a bit overkill. Or recopy a file at deploy time, but that's not clean and does not work well with dependencies management.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

While it is still early days (at the time of this post), this appears to be exactly what Google Artifact Repository aims to provide.  See:

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs

This is a service which provides management for various artifacts including:

- Docker images
- Node.JS packages (think npm)
- Maven Java packages
- others ...

The service is still in beta (and some parts still in alpha) so it may be a touch too early for many applications.  However, I could imagine you publishing your NodeJS packages to your own artifact repository and then defining those packages as dependencies in your deployed Cloud Function logic which would then provide commonality and consistency.